# Apply CSS to div with multiple classes

Tags: html, css

I want to apply these css settings:

```
margin-right: 10px;
width: 65px;
```

to this html-code:

```
<div class="field field-name-prefix">
Test
</div>
<div class="field field-name-vorname">
Test2
</div>
```

As you can see I have two divs with the same class "field". 
But I want to apply the css just to "field field-name-prefix".
How can I do that?

Comment: Which selectors have you tried already?

Answer (score 2):

In the css you just need to refer to the class you want:

```
.field-name-prefix {
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 65px;
}
```

Comment: Glad to help! If I answered your question, mark it as asnwered :) @L.Kleinmann

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using different class tag for the Test 2 div, it will be easy here. Just apply the properties to the class field-name-vorname and that will do the work. See the example:

```css
.field{
       background-color:red;
    }
    .field-name-prefix{
       /* css for the given class */  
    }
    .field-name-vorname{
      
      margin-right: 10px;
      width: 65px;
    }
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="field field-name-prefix">
  Test 1
  </div>
  <div class="field field-name-vorname">
  Test 2
  <div>
</div>
```